# Material properties databases (BRDF)

Tags: reflection, raytracing

I am working on a new **Ray Tracing** project which has to provide highly realistic simulation.

I have a problem with calculating reflection on target. I wanted to use the **BRDF** (bidirectional reflectance distribution function) model which gives information about diffuse and specular reflection to calculate how much energy was reflected from the target

**What I wanted to ask:**

1. I was wondering if there are any databases with measurements of **BRDF** for different materials (including incoming light direction and outgoing direction) and for different wavelengths of the light source (the most interesting for me is the laser source 800-1600nm)?
2. The second thing, do you know any good databases with material properties like: ambient, diffuse, specular, shininess and roughness of surface values.

**What I've already found:**

http://www.merl.com/brdf/

https://globe3d.sourceforge.io/g3d_html/gl-materials__ads.htm

http://www.cs.columbia.edu/CAVE/software/curet/

https://github.com/POV-Ray/povray/tree/master/distribution/include

But if I understand correctly all of them used a lamp as a light source and I don't see any references to the wavelengths of the light source. Moreover, there aren't any good values of material properties.

I am quite new in this so if you have any advice or I wrote something wrong, I will be grateful for any correction and information connecting with this topic.

Comment: http://rgl.epfl.ch/materials